# if ('False' == 'True') ... else if ('False' == 'True') meaning

Tags: javascript

I am currently writing a Chrome extension and needed to replace/override some functions on the main page ( because someone loved to write colors as javascript variables in the scope of methods ... 100 times -.- ) ... so i was looking through these methods and got to a method that has code as below:

```
if ('False' == 'True') {
    ...
    return false;
}
else if ('False' == 'True') {
    ...
    return false;
}
```

thereafter my head begin the crash completely ... if i am not wrong this `else if` is written like this:

```
if(false){
    ...
    return false;
}
else if(false){
    ...
    return false;    
}
```

I never saw something like that before, so i am extremely confused ... 
Has this any useful meaning in javascript? what could be on the mind of the developer when he wrote this code? why should i write such an expression that is always false ... and then define an else with the same condition?

Comment: this is unreacable code. it will not execute the blocks since it always false.

Comment: "i was locking throu there methods [sic]" ew. Also, it looks like the writer of this page didn't write it very well.

Comment: Welcome to the world of completely nonsensical code other people write and you have to deal with.

Comment: Are you looking at the source or output? Is is possible there's some source code that looks like `if ('@Variable1' == '@Variable2') {` that is rendered in a way that doesn't look like it makes sense in the output?

Comment: Because there are many who don't know what they're doing. That's probably the case. That code will never run. If the software works fine, then you can delete it. It's there for no reason

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is not constructive.

Comment: @JasonP this is the output, its a complete javascript function that appears on the page

Comment: @CodingGorilla you may right, i was struggling if this may be the right place to ask such a question, what this kind if-else mean.

Comment: @JamesCoyle where is the exit?!! i don't want to stay!

Comment: @JPVenson The thing to keep in mind is that questions are not only for your use, but they should also be useful to people who might have similar problems in the future.  This might be more appropriate for http://programmers.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @CodingGorilla i never intend to. i just wounder what this code could mean, so i thought this could be a general question about javascript code design. I will move the question soon.

Comment: As i recognized this code block as dead, i just wounder why it appears on an live webpage. Its seems so unreal, that i thought the lack of knowledge over this function may be on my side. As you told me what i expected, i now know its not my fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is it's a [pre-processor inserting constants](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/) with the assumption that a dead-code removal tool like Uglify will exclude it from the final build.

**2019 Edit**: new link above. Old link available on [web archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20160107221245/https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#defineplugin)

Answer (score 2):

'False' and 'True' are actually strings, 'True' == 'False' should always evaluate to false. As a result, none of the code will evaluate as both conditions are set to false ('if' and 'else if').